# What is the most elegant way to stop a process in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have an asyncio powered project. I have a process function which starts every time I need via `asyncio.run_in_executor()` function.
Here's my function:

```
def fn():
    print(f"run: {os.getpid()}")

    def __kill_itself():
        print(f"kill itself: {os.getpid()}")
        os.system(f"kill {os.getpid()}")

    ...
```

Once I need to stop my process `kill_itself` will be called. But this way raises the `BrokenProcessPool` exception. After that executor becomes unusable.

```
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending
```

What is the correct way to stop a process by itself? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031253/how-to-fix-brokenprocesspool-error-for-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor

Comment: How bout putting the kill command inside a try except block, then catch the error and print something like "the process was successfully killed".

Comment: `asyncio.run_in_executor()` returns a `Future` so probably `.cancel()`.